# Phalcon route contains a word

Tags: php, regex, phalcon

I have a problem.
I have routes:

```
$router->add('/news/{alias}(/?)', array(
'module' => 'frontend',
'controller' => 'news',
'action' => 'view',
'news_id' => 1,
'lang' => 'md',))->setName('news_view_short_e');
```

And:

```
$router->add('/news/index/...
```

How I can check {alias} if he contains "index"?

```
/news/{alias:(?!index)+}(/?)
```

Not working.
Please help.

My links:

site.com/news/index/ - **all news** 
site.com/news/anlinter/ - **category** 
site.com/news/231213-newsfriendly-url/ - **news view**

Comment: Can you update your question with example links you want to achieve?

Comment: updated my question with links!

Comment: Do you want to match the route that contains index or the one which does not contain index?

Comment: Yes. Example: if I go to url site.com/news/anlinter I get 404 not found. If I remove route with {alias}, I get page normal. How I can check alias if he contains (anlinter|index) ?

Answer (score 0):

This site is really helpful for understanding and testing your regexes: https://regexr.com/

Putting there your regex of `(?!index)+` will tell you that there is a "Negative Lookahead", which "Specifies a group that can not match after the main expression (if it matches, the result is discarded)."

The problem is with your `?!`. I did some quick test in my local machine, where I eliminated the `?!`, and the route got matched correctly.

Comment: How I can fix it?

Comment: /news/{alias:(index)+}(/?)

Comment: Exactly. Like the user above said: `/news/{alias:(index)+}(/?)`.

BTW, if this answer solved the issue, mark it as accepted, please.

Answer (score 0):

Test, `/news/{alias:((?!index).)+`

That worked out for me.

Comment: you should enclose your code fragments in backticks (`) to improve the readability of your posts. [More info on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)